# GWT Clientsided logging without RPC

Tags: gwt, logging

I just read the [Developer's Guide - Logging](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Client_vs_Server_side_Logging)  and it says that the client-sided logging implement throw RPC calls (see [Remote Logging](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging) ).

My application doesn't use RPC and it is supposed to be hosted on a webserver which doesn't have Java support (so now RPC usable). Is there still a possibility to use the GWT logger on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try another logger....see here: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick example of gwt-log below..

Add this line in ***.gwt.xml** file. Its in parent package of your client side source. The top most package..

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
```

Add this in .java file, lets say in the onModuleLoad() method

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("NameOfYourLogger");
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "this message should get logged");
```